# Liberty Profile + Servlet 2.4

Tags: java, servlets, classloader, websphere-liberty

Hi i hope you can help me please:), i have a web application that uses servlet 2.4, i Know is very old but i am trying to deploy this app on Liberty Profile  8.5.5.3 , Liberty Profile works with "Features" and i am using "jsp-2.2" , i read about that feature and it uses Servlet 3.0, it is suppose that i can use other servlet version if i use the classLoader configuration but when i start my Server Liberty Profile Web this uses Servlet 3.0  , it is possible work with Liberty Profile and Servlet 2.4?.

My server.xml configuration is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="server01">

<!-- Enable features -->
 <featureManager>
   <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
 </featureManager>
 <application id="webapptest" name="webapp type="ear" location="D:/LBP/webapp.ear">
   <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="mySharedLib"></classloader>
 </application>
 <library id="mySharedLib">
    <fileset dir="D:/LBP/wlp/usr/servers/server-prueba01/myLib" includes="*.jar" />
 </library>
<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
 <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9088"
              httpsPort="9443" />
 </server>
```

In "commonLibraryRef" i put the "servlet-api-2.4" jar

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you just to update application and web deployment descriptor to Java EE 6 (Servlet 3.0):

```
// web.xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

// application.xml
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
```

and try your application. I'd say that most of the 2.4 servlets will run fine in 3.0.

If you are trying to migrate from other application server, you could try [IBM WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/compmig.html) to see how many changes are required to migrate application.

Comment: Hi friend i did try that too but i must add that i work with old spring version that has dependency to servlet-version (2.4), it is a big application so i am trying to know if there is a way using servlet 2.4 version , if not i will keep in mind to update my spring version (I was using WAS and it works but know i must use Liberty Profile)

Comment: @CharlyPL As far as I know, you cant run J2EE 1.4 apps in Liberty and replace servlet jars. So when you changed descriptors, what kind of errors did you have?

Comment: The same Errors Exception = java.lang.ClassCastException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet
probeid = 213
Stack Dump = java.lang.ClassCastException: mx.telecom.company.compatibility.ws.ControlWebService cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Comment: @CharlyPL But I hope you dont have servlet-api-2.4.jar in your WEB-INF/lib? If you have, try to remove it. But this error worries me, that you are also using old web services - JAX-RPC - which is also not supported by Liberty.

Comment: Servlet-api-2.4 is not in my web-inf/lib, i am using maven , the servlet-api2.4 scope is "provided" , buddy the web application is old from 2003 or something like that, so i'm just trying to know if Liberty Profile can support those old technologies or there is no way to run up my app using servlet 2.4 on this Server , Thanks :)

Comment: @CharlyPL If application is that old, you can try to run it on WAS 8.5.5 Full profile, which supports J2EE 1.4 apps. For Liberty you will have to first migrate your app to Java EE 6. Sorry man...

Comment: Ok man thanks, i am running that web application on WAS 8.5 ,i was trying on Liberty Profile but i have many problems with that, i will migrate my application to J2EE6 first